# Indian Passport holder with a Multiple Entry US Visa traveling to Belize

Tags: indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, belize

So my friend just invited me to travel with her to Belize. I contacted travelbelize.org and they tell me there are not aware of any repatriation fees that need to paid upon arrival. But I see all these posts on Wikipedia and Quora that there's a $600 repatriation fee that every Indian needs to pay on entry. The Belize embassies won't answer unfortunately.
Any Indian here with a US visa who traveled to Belize this year or maybe 2016? I feel like I can only rely on first hand experience.

Answer (score 1):

You do not require a Visa for Belize but **you do have to pay** that $600 Fee

> N.B. U.S. Citizens and Holders of U.S. Permanent Resident Cards/U.S. Multiple Entries Visas do not require a visa to enter Belize.

Source: [Embassy of Belize in Washington, D.C.](http://www.embassyofbelize.gov.bz/consular-services/obtaining-a-visa.html)

Now onto the Fee part.

> Belize (BZ)
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Visitors must hold at least USD 50.- per person per day and   documents required for their next destination.
> - Nationals of Bangladesh, India, Pakistan and Sri Lanka must  pay a repatriation fee of BZD 1,200.- on arrival.
> - Nationals of China (People's Rep.) must pay a repatriation    fee of BZD 3,000.- on arrival.
> - Extension of stay possible for those listed under visa   exemptions.

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=BZ&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=AI&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C)

You asked for any first hand experiences only, mine is not. Timatic is much more accurate than what my experiences would've been.